# How can I ensure my ansible module only runs on the master?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

### short version

I want to make sure that my module is only ever run on the ansible master (so as a `local_action`, or with `connection: local`). And, if possible, I'd like my module to know the path to the ansible project root without forcing the user to supply that as an argument.

### actual use-case

The ansible module I'm writing is composed of two executables:

- the python executable -- which uses the AnsibleModule class to guarantee a stable interface to ansible.
- the ruby executable -- which uses the Hiera API. Again, partly for stability, partly because I'd have to write hiera from scratch in python otherwise.

The only issue is that, in order to run the ruby executable, I am forced to assume that:

- the thing is being run on master, and
- the user running the playbook has the ansible project root as their CWD.

I have to assume these things because, since ansible doesn't know about the ruby executable, that executable's only available on the master. So if it's run on a slave machine, it'll almost certainly simply fail because it can't find the ruby file. Worse, it's probably a security issue; if there's a file upload vuln on the ansible slave, a malicious user could ensure that the path `./library/<my_executable>.rb` *does* contain an executable (which, say, starts a reverse shell).

I want this to ship with secure defaults, but I'm not familiar enough with what ansible's doing under the hood to make sure that happens.

Both executables are finished (with the exception of this part, which as mentioned above is using the dirty hack of using a hardcoded path and hoping they're on master) and the module works. It's readable, maintainable, thoroughly unit-tested and documented, and I'm not rearchitecting it on the offchance that someone thinks they've thought of a better way to do things. Which is not to say that I have thought of objectively the best way, just that I won't find an answer which simply tells me to "do everything in one executable" helpful. Because that's answering a question I have no interest in asking.

Answer (score 2):

Modules are meant to be executed on any host. First thing ansible does is packaging the module, before it invokes it on the remote hosts(s) and there's no way of preventing it. The data available to the module when executed is very limited, as it is restricted to what the user of the module explicitly passed to it in the task. Unless you know the name of the control host I think there is no easy way - to do it with a module.

Even though that means to re-architect a little bit: Your use case sounds like you would rather create an **action plugin** instead. Action plugins are used exactly the same as you'd use a module, but are never transferred to the remote hosts but are executed locally on the control host.

Unfortunately action plugins are the least documented - means they are not even mentioned [in the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html)... so here's where you can have a look at some examples: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/ce2b18174e2a767f34932073220f43cb889d54d4/lib/ansible/plugins/action

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation)**.
I have delegate_to previously to only execute tasks on the master control host, either by using 127.0.0.1 or localhost and it works well.

local_action is also briefly referenced under the delegation topic.
Examples as per the documentation:

```
---

- hosts: webservers
  serial: 5

  tasks:

  - name: take out of load balancer pool
    command: /usr/bin/take_out_of_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

  - name: actual steps would go here
    yum: name=acme-web-stack state=latest

  - name: add back to load balancer pool
    command: /usr/bin/add_back_to_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

and the shorthand version of delegate_to, which is local_action:

```
---

# ...

  tasks:

  - name: take out of load balancer pool
    local_action: command /usr/bin/take_out_of_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}

# ...

  - name: add back to load balancer pool
    local_action: command /usr/bin/add_back_to_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
```